# Dialogflow not detecting "Exit conversation" intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to override the default answers for the not-deleteable "exit intent" that Dialogflow [provides](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/reference/intents). This intent is not visible in the intent list of my agent but according to the documentation and to empiric evidence, it's there. The question is:

How do I override its default answers?

**My** exit intent is called "Exit conversation".

1. I tried using the event 'actions_intent_CANCEL' that the docs provide, but it doesn't seem to work.
   [Image. Intent name and Events.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHKmU.png)
2. I have set the intent as 'end of conversation' in the Dialogflow Console.
   [Image. Responses.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDfvu.png)
3. I have enabled the webhook call for that intent, and connected the webhook to a function that closes the conversation with the same answer that I set up in the Responses field of the Intent Console. [Image. Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkpf7.png)

Additional images:

[Image. Training phrases. It's in spanish :) but it basically says "cancel", "i dont want to continue", etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u5U5.png)

[Image. Actions and parameters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1bKm.png)

The thing is, it is not always even recognizing MY intent. Depending on the current flow situation, it sometimes goes to the default intent, sometimes goes to mine. When I type 'cancel'/'cancelar' it does not always detect my "Exit conversation" intent, it stays in the current intent and closes the conversation with the default exit Dialogflow intent: 'Ok, cancelled.' or something like that.
It sometimes gets mine, though, and gives my answer, but its seems to do so in an unpredictable way.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Does Dialogflow have a default Exit Intent?**

Not necessarily. There *is* a default Cancel Intent (which is the same thing) when using Actions on Google, but this doesn't show up in Dialogflow as an Intent. It shows up as an Event.

The table on the page you referred to shows the Intent name, but this is only available if you're working with Actions on Google v2 directly. The third column shows the Event name that it appears as in Dialogflow.

[image: Table of Common Intents]

**So why does it seem to exit if I say "exit" or "cancel"?**

This is handled by the Assistant before it hits Dialogflow by default. So there isn't a "hidden" Dialogflow Intent that handles it.

You need to specifically create your own Intent to handle it if you want.

**That sounds like it is splitting hairs. But ok, how?**

You can [opt into cancel events](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/conversation-exits) in Dialogflow by

1. Creating a new Intent. (You can name it whatever you want, but something like "End Conversation" or "quit.event" is typical.)
2. Set the Event field to "actions_intent_CANCEL".
3. You can then set responses, set webhooks, etc, just like you would for other events. You should probably also set the "Ends Conversation" checkbox, but if you don't, it will end anyway.

[image: actions_intent_CANCEL illustration]

**But I did that! Why does it only work sometimes?**

Your description suggested that you included training phrases in your "Exit Conversation" Intent.

For any Intent in Dialogflow, you should provide *either* training phrases *or* an Event, but not both. By providing both, you may be confusing Dialogflow.

**So how do I add additional phrases that should be used to quit?**

Make a *second Intent* with the other training phrases and without the Event. I usually call it something like "quit", so it is in the list near the other Intent.

[image: Quit Intent]

**So I need two Intents? How can I handle that in my code? Doesn't that mean I need twice as much code?**

Remember that Intents represent *what the user says or does* and not how you handle it.

I typically handle everything in a webhook and set the Action string to the same thing for both. The webhook library I use, [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/), can determine how to handle things base on that Action string. (Other libraries don't use this field, and you don't need to set it if your library doesn't use it.)

If you're using the Dialogflow library (and it looks like you are) for your webhook, you can just have both Intent names call the same handler function. It might look something like this:

```
function exitConversation( agent ){
  console.log( "Cancelled" );
  agent.end( "Goodbye" );
}
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set( "quit.event", exitConversation );
intentMap.set( "quit", exitConversation );
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. Second, I made the second intent with the training phrases, and I took the training prashes out of the intent that has the event field filled. But I did not understand what you meant by "I typically handle everything in a webhook and set the Action string to the same thing for both". Do I have to fill the Actions field with something? In both intents that field is empty. The thing is not working and that might be the cause.

Comment: The comment about the "action" field is only relevant if your library uses it. The default Dialogflow library does not. You shouldn't need to set it if you're using the library from Dialogflow.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, it may be useful to update your original question to show sample conversations that include the Intents as you have them configured now and illustrate it not working, along with any logs that might indicate what it *is* doing.